# Conditional or loop statements in rtf template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rtf

I have predefined `rtf` template file `RTF_Template.rtf` as follows:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 \fswiss Helvetica;}{\f1 Courier;}}
{\colortbl;\red255\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue255;}
\widowctrl\hyphauto

{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 \b \fs36 FirstName LastName\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 {\b UEI:} 103910\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 {\b Sex:\u160?}Female\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 {\b DOB:} 10/31/1980\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 {\b Email:} sample@email.com \par}
```

I am making changing in this format something like:

```
rtf_template = Rails.root.join('doc', 'rtf_templates', 'RTF_Template.rtf')
content = File.read(rtf_template)
content.gsub!('FirstName LastName', @student.full_name)
content.gsub!('UEI', StudentIdentifier.primary_identifier.first&.name)
content.gsub!('103910', @student.primary_identifier&.value)
content.gsub!('Female', @student.gender)
content.gsub!('10/31/1980', @student.date_of_birth.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))
content.gsub!('sample@email.com', @student.email)
```

**Problem:**

Currently, I am only showing the first `StudentIdentifier` which is the primary one on line: `content.gsub!('UEI', StudentIdentifier.primary_identifier.first&.name)`

and setting value for same identifier on Line: `content.gsub!('103910', @student.primary_identifier&.value)`

The user can have multiple identifiers and value against that each identifier.
I can access those all identifier using a loop `@student.identifiers.each do |p_id|`
then identifier name in `p_id[0]` and value in `p_id[1]`

I want to show all identifiers on the same place (after name, before sex) in the same template.

Answer (score 0):

Your code simply needs to substitute one placeholder with a sequence of RTF code lines.

Template:

{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 \fswiss Helvetica;}{\f1 Courier;}}
{\colortbl;\red255\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue255;}
\widowctrl\hyphauto

```
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 \b \fs36 FirstName LastName\par}
identifier_list
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 {\b Sex:\u160?}Female\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 {\b DOB:} 10/31/1980\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 {\b Email:} sample@email.com \par}
```

And then concatenate your identifier name / value pairs including the surrounding RTF code, for example

```
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 {\b UEI1:} 103911\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 {\b UEI2:} 103912\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 {\b UEI3:} 103913\par}
```

And finally replace the placeholder

```
content.gsub!('identifier_list', myIdentifierListsWithRTF)
```

(note: I am no ruby on rails programmer so I can only give the idea, not the actual code)